# to_date ora-01847 day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

Tags: sql, oracle, runtime-error

I am trying to execute the below query but getting this error:

`to_date ora-01847 day of month must be between 1 and last day of month`

query is to check overlaping of date and time in two different tables

`table1 (emp_num1 number,start_date1 date,start_time1 varchar2,end_date1 date,end_time2 varchar2)`

`table2(emp_num2 number,start_date2 date,start_time2 varchar2,end_date2 date,end_time2 varchar2)`

```
select *
  from table1 t1
      ,table2 t2
 where t1.emp_num 1 = t2.emp_num2
   and to_timestamp(to_char(start_date1,'DD-MON-YYYY')||' '||NVL(start_time1,'00:00'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')
       between
      to_timestamp(to_char(start_date2,'DD-MON-YYYY')||' '||NVL(start_time2,'00:00'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')
       and
      to_timestamp(to_char(end_date2,'DD-MON-YYYY')||' '||NVL(end_time2,'00:00'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')
      or
      to_timestamp(to_char(end_date1,'DD-MON-YYYY')||' '||NVL(end_time1,'00:00'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')
       between
      to_timestamp(to_char(start_date2,'DD-MON-YYYY')||' '||NVL(start_time2,'00:00'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')
       and
      to_timestamp(to_char(end_date2,'DD-MON-YYYY')||' '||NVL(end_time2,'00:00'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')
```

the above query resulting the error:

`to_date ora-01847 day of month must be between 1 and last day of month`

I tried running query

```
select to_timestamp(to_char(start_date1,'DD-MON-YYYY')||' '||NVL(start_time1,'00:00'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') from table1
```

no error is encountered.

Comment: Is it possible that one of the four date fields has `NULL` values?

Comment: Try the test query with NULL substituted for `start_date1`:  I bet it gives the same error.

Comment: date fields are mandatory fields...so none of the tables have null date fileds

Comment: Then try running variations of your test query against all the fields and tables involved.  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

To reproduce the error:

```
SELECT NVL(SYSDATE,'00:00')
FROM DUAL
```

> ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

The [NVL() description](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions119.htm) says:

> The arguments expr1 and expr2 can have any data type. If their data
>   types are different, then Oracle Database implicitly converts one to
>   the other. If they cannot be converted implicitly, then the database
>   returns an error. The implicit conversion is implemented as follows:
>
> - If expr1 is character data, then Oracle Database converts expr2 to the data type of expr1 before comparing them and returns VARCHAR2 in
>     the character set of expr1.
> - If expr1 is numeric, then Oracle Database determines which argument has the highest numeric precedence, implicitly converts the other
>     argument to that data type, and returns that data type.

So we can simplify the reproduce case:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('00:00')
FROM DUAL
```

Since you don't provide a format, it's assuming `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, and thus the error: '00' is not a valid day.

*(I don't really know what you're trying to do but you can try using pure date functions.)*

Comment: But per the table definitions in the query, the start_time and end_time fields are declared as VARCHAR2.  Thus I don't think this is it.  Great idea, though.

Comment: Sorry then. I didn't know the column types so I just guessed.

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting is need to be fixed. Here's your initial setup:

```
SELECT '07-MAR-2013' start_date -- char
     , NULL          start_time -- char
 FROM dual
/
```

Final formatting - NO NVL required. But if you must then add NVL(start_time, '00:00'):

```
SELECT to_timestamp(start_date||' '||start_time, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') t_stamp
  FROM
  (
   SELECT '07-MAR-2013'      start_date -- char
        , NVL(NULL, '00:00') start_time -- char - NVL is optional 
    FROM dual
  )
 /

 3/7/2013 12:00:00.000000000 AM
```

You will get the same result if you remove start_time compl. Generally to compare dates you should use TRUNC to remove time portion.

```
SELECT to_timestamp('07-MAR-2013', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') start_date_only 
  FROM dual
/   

3/7/2013 12:00:00.000000000 AM

 SELECT trunc(to_timestamp('07-MAR-2013', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) start_date_only FROM dual
 /

3/7/2013
```